# How to display caret symbol in wxPython static text widget?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
        self.diffusivity_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=u'Thermal Diffusivity [m^2/s]')
```

I would like to display the caret symbol so that my static text can look exactly like this: "Thermal Diffusivity [m^2/s]." After looking online, I tried doing this:

```
        self.diffusivity_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=u'Thermal Diffusivity [m\u20382/s]')
```

Doing so displayed the caret symbol, but it was not elevated like I want it to look. Instead, the text looks like this:

[image]

What can I do now? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Eh? The ASCII character with ordinal 94 (5e in hex), rendering as `^`, is perfectly valid UTF-8 (UTF-8 being, after all, a proper superset of 7-bit ASCII).

Comment: You almost certainly want Unicode 005E.  Alternatively just type the character in a text editor which writes the file in UTF-8.

Comment: ...are you perhaps using a widget set that treats `^` as a sigil for "the next character is the hotkey"? That's a question about wxWidgets, not about UTF-8.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've just tested it in wxPython, `^` has no special meaning in `wx.StaticText`, it's displayed fine.

Comment: Hey @randomir, I think the problem may have been that I'm writing in unicode (notice the "u" before the string).

Comment: @Aang, it shouldn't have been. Why do you think it was?

Comment: @Aang, ...so, you include a screenshot of what `u'Thermal Diffusivity [m\u20382/s]'` renders as -- but how does `u'Thermal Diffusivity [m^2/s]'` render for you?

Comment: The caret does not show up at all when I just do u'Thermal Diffusivity [m^2/s].'

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to write something like: `m²/s`, you could use Unicode codepoint called [`SUPERSCRIPT TWO`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm), `\u00b2`, which looks like: `²`.

So, you can say:

```
self.diffusivity_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=u'Thermal Diffusivity [m\u00b2/s]')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you dude!

Answer (score 1):

wxPython provides the `fancytext` widget pretty much just for this purpose. It provides superscripting and subscripting support as well as other text styling. Here's an example using your text:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.fancytext as fancytext

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Superscripting')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_panel_paint)

        self.Show()

    def on_panel_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        text = "Thermal Diffusivity [m<sup>^</sup>2/s]."
        w, h = fancytext.GetExtent(text, dc)
        fancytext.RenderToDC(text, dc, 20, 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```